# Почему не работает фильтрация JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Контроллер:

```
async getAll(req, res){  //sorting
            let {carManufacturerId, bodyTypeId,limit,page} = req.body
            page = page || 1
            limit = limit || 9
            let offset = page * limit - limit
            let cars;
            if (!carManufacturerId && !bodyTypeId){
                cars = await Car.findAll({limit, offset})
            }
            if (carManufacturerId && !bodyTypeId){
                cars = await Car.findAll({where: {carManufacturerId}, limit, offset})
            }
            if (!carManufacturerId && bodyTypeId){
                cars = await Car.findAll({where: {bodyTypeId}, limit, offset})
            }
            if (carManufacturerId && bodyTypeId){
                cars = await Car.findAll({where: {bodyTypeId,carManufacturerId}, limit, offset})
            }
            return res.json(cars)
        }
```

Роутер:

```
router.get('/',carController.getAll)
```

имеющийся JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Crown Majesta",
        "price": 1000000,
        "carManufacturerId": 1,
        "bodyTypeId": 1,
        "year": 2005,
        "engine": "5.5 TI",
        "drive": "передний",
        "img": "0a9db193-851f-4216-8a94-cd5ca9777dd2.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2021-12-01T07:01:06.085Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-01T07:01:06.085Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Wrangler",
        "price": 500000,
        "carManufacturerId": 2,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "year": 2001,
        "engine": "3.4 ",
        "drive": "Полный",
        "img": "ea1331fb-48f2-4031-aaf2-38927f1462fa.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2021-12-01T07:18:42.572Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-01T07:18:42.572Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Corolla",
        "price": 4999000,
        "carManufacturerId": 1,
        "bodyTypeId": 2,
        "year": 2003,
        "engine": "1.5 AMD",
        "drive": "Передний",
        "img": "2efa1d74-e3f8-4c49-a823-8791768be03c.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2021-12-01T07:19:53.236Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-01T07:19:53.236Z"
    }
]
```

При запросе *http://localhost:5000/api/car?bodyTypeId=2*, то есть при запросе уже написанной сортировке по полю **bodyTypeId**, выбрасывается этот же, неотсортированный JSON

Comment: А у вас сортировка или фильтрация всё-таки? Какой вы ожидаете результат запроса? Добавьте пример ожидаемого ответа в вопрос.

Comment: Все верно, фильтрация. Ожидаемый JSON - такой JSON, который при запросе http://localhost:5000/api/car?bodyTypeId=2 ,  имеет только объекты в которых параметры ключей bodyTypeId равны **2**

Comment: `router.get('/',carController.getAll)` и `let {...} = req.body` - ничего не смущает?

Comment: что не так с этим ?

Comment: ну подумайте, какие варианты что с этим не так?

Comment: нет вариантов, расскажите в чем ошибся

Answer (score 0):

ответом было,
вместо:

`req.body` использовать `req.query`